# Behaviour of library call localtime() on different Linux platforms

Tags: c, linux, time, timezone, embedded-linux

I want to know if `localtime` works differently on different platforms if timezone is set same in both. If it does,what are dependent parameters other than timezone?

I run this in 2 platforms:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    time_t t,t1;//,result;
    double d1;
    struct tm *tm;
    t1 = 1384496356;

    tm = localtime(&t1);

    printf("tm->tm_hour %d tm->tm_min %d\n",tm->tm_hour,tm->tm_min);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs
`tm->tm_mday 15 tm->tm_hour 11 tm->tm_min 33`

and 
`tm->tm_mday 15 tm->tm_hour 6 tm->tm_min 3`

Comment: As dependent as hardware clock?

Comment: When I run `hwclock --debug` It outputs
`hwclock from util-linux-ng 2.16.1
hwclock: Open of /dev/rtc failed, errno=2: No such file or directory.
No usable clock interface found.
Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.`

Comment: The difference is 5 hours 30 minutes, which is the offset of IST (India Standard Time) from UTC.  What is the value of TZ set to on the two systems?  There's usually a system-wide setting, sometimes in `/etc/timezone`, that gives a default setting for the time zone. I also note that the code you show does not give the output you show.  Such discrepancies in the question raise warning flags; what else aren't you telling us?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : When I do `date +%Z` it gives `UTC`.
When I do `env`,It does'nt show `TZ`. Where it is located.?Where to find its value?

Comment: @Arya Then it seems the time is just configured wrong on one of your machines - perhaps someone set it to UTC on one machine, and the local time on the other at some point. Are you running ntp ?

Comment: There's a binary file `/etc/localtime` on one of my machines; it holds binary data that seems to map to the time zone information.

Comment: `man 5 tzfile` gives information of relevance, too.

Comment: I'm also puzzled that the time you quote in your program breaks down to a date/time 15-6-19 in UTC (instead of 15-6-3 as claimed in your question).  I don't see where the 16 minute difference could come from.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That is the problem.There is no `/etc/localtime` on my both of machines. Ok I will copy exact outputs here.For same input.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I m running ntp.

Comment: @Arya Perhaps you are running uClibc, or some other embedded variants. If it's uClibc, it uses /etc/TZ instead of /etc/localtime

Comment: I got point.TZ was nt setting either from my application nor there was /etc/localtime.So it was taking default i.e. UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware clock and the time zone define the local time.

Comment: When I run `hwclock --debug` It outputs
`hwclock from util-linux-ng 2.16.1
hwclock: Open of /dev/rtc failed, errno=2: No such file or directory.
No usable clock interface found.
Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.`

Comment: Doing `man hwclock` and reading might teach you that using the option `-f` or `--rtc=` allows you to specify an alternative to `/dev/rtc` like `/dev/rtc0` or `/dev/rtc1` or ....

Answer (score 0):

t1 in your code is time in seconds since 00:00:00 UTC, 1970-01-01.  If you are getting different times on different machines, it means real time clocks on these machines are not synchronized, assuming they are configured to be in the same timezones.